# number data from pagination not working move page

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, pagination, numbers

i am implementing a pagination from an api. But i have a problem when assigning the number of the data where the number returns to number1 every time i move the page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsrjr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XerIT.png)

Comment: Please write code part too.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put a counter in the Records loop for fixing and returning records with this counter. cou

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).